# Pattern matching on enum with value inside it?

Tags: rust, enums

If I have a enum that imitates an option type, it can either contain some value, or nothing:

```
enum option {
    some(u8),
    none,
}
```

Then I can pattern match it like this:

```
let x = option::some(8);

match x {
    some => println!("some"),
    none => println!("none"),
}
```

But what if I want to pattern match the value inside the some?
Intuitively, I think it would be something like so:

```
match x {
    some(x) => println!("{}", x),
    none => println!("none"),
}
```

But Rust has no idea what this is.
I also try to see if the `some` itself is the `u8` value:

```
match x {
    some => println!("{}", some),
    none => println!("none"),
}
```

This also does not work.
How do I get the value inside the enum?

Comment: "Rust has no idea what this is" - and what's the error it generates? The code should work as written, so we clearly don't know something about your real problem.

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
let x = option::some(8);
match x {
    option::some(x) => println!("{}", x),
    option::none => println!("none"),
}
```

But keep in mind this all-lower-case naming is against the standard Rust naming conventions. Your code will look much better like this:

```
enum Option {
    Some(u8),
    None
}

pub fn main() {
    let x = Option::Some(8);
    match x {
        Option::Some(x) => println!("{}", x),
        Option::None => println!("none"),
    }
}
```

You might see that note as nitpicking, but as you add more and more code, that will become a much bigger issue. So it's good to build the right habits from the beginning.

Comment: It's also good to keep in mind that Rust already includes [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html) :)

Answer (score 1):

Completment to at54321's answer:

> Then I can pattern match it like this:
>
> ```
> let x = option::some(8);
>
> match x {
>     some => println!("some"),
>     none => println!("none"),
> }
> ```

That does not actually *work*, it will always match the first branch (always print `some`), and if you read the compiler's warning it'll tell you that:

```
warning: unreachable pattern
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
10 |     some => println!("some"),
   |     ---- matches any value
11 |     none => println!("none"),
   |     ^^^^ unreachable pattern
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unreachable_patterns)]` on by default

warning: unused variable: `some`
  --> src/main.rs:10:5
   |
10 |     some => println!("some"),
   |     ^^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_some`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_variables)]` on by default

warning: unused variable: `none`
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     none => println!("none"),
   |     ^^^^ help: if this is intentional, prefix it with an underscore: `_none`
```

So it tells you that `none` is not reachable (because the first branch is a catchall), and it hints that `some` and `none` are *new bindings*, not enum variants.

> But what if I want to pattern match the value inside the some? Intuitively, I think it would be something like so:
>
> ```
> match x {
>     some(x) => println!("{}", x),
>     none => println!("none"),
> }
> ```

If, again, you read the error message, the compiler gives you the solution (though the why is not clear):

```
error[E0531]: cannot find tuple struct or tuple variant `some` in this scope
   --> src/main.rs:10:5
    |
10  |     some(x) => println!("some"),
    |     ^^^^
    |
help: a tuple variant with a similar name exists
    |
10  |     Some(x) => println!("some"),
    |     ~~~~
help: consider importing this tuple variant
    |
1   | use crate::option::some;
    |
```

The issue here is that Rust enums are *scoped*, which you can see from... the creation of the variant. If you use `option::some` when creating a value, why would the `option::` bit be optional when matching it? And the answer's it's not (and in fact it's generally a good idea to include it, in order to avoid risks of collision / ambiguity between matching a variant and creating a new one).

It's also not entirely clear why you're creating an option type when [there's one in the standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html), I will say.